# How can I create the rational numbers with these 2 functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

I have these functions
$F(x) = x + 1$ and
$G(x) = -1/x$

I can only use $x$ as $1$
So $x = 1$
I can use these functions as many times I want
and I can use them as composite functions, for example, I can do
$F\circ G\circ F\circ F$ and so on. But I can’t add them together or divide them etc.
What I want to do is to prove that I can create the rational numbers Q with these two functions.

I thought about this today but couldn’t found an answer, any help is appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: *And I can use them as composite functions* --- More importantly, is this the **only** way you can use them, or can you add, subtract, multiply, divide functions or perform some other operations with them?

Comment: Could it be that you mean $g(x) =-1/x$ or something like that?

Comment: Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset the math in your questions.

Comment: I can only use them composite functions. fogofogof I can use them in any order as I want and as many times I want.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). For example:

To get $\frac{155}{67}$:

$155 = 67\times 2 + 21 \tag 1$

$67 = 21\times 3 + 4 \tag 2$

$21 = 4\times 5 + 1 \tag 3$

From $(1)$, $\frac{155}{67} = 2+ \frac{21}{67} = F(F(\frac{21}{67})) = F(F(G(\frac{67}{21})))$

From $(2)$, $\frac{67}{21} = 3+ \frac{4}{21} = F(F(F(\frac{4}{21}))) = F(F(F(G(\frac{21}{4}))))$

From $(3)$, $\frac{21}{4} = 5 + \frac{1}{4} = F(F(F(F(F(\frac{1}{4}))))) = F(F(F(F(F(G(4))))))$

And finally $4 = F(F(F(F(1))))$, so

$\frac{155}{67}=F(F(G(F(F(F(G(F(F(F(F(F(G(F(F(F(F(1)))))))))))))))))$

**Edit**: I just realized that I misread $G(x)=1/x$. The OP has $G(x)= -1/x$ so a slight variation of the Euclidean algorithm is needed. For example:

$155= 67\times 3 - 46$ so $\frac{155}{67}= 3- \frac{46}{67}= F(F(F(-\frac{46}{67}))) = F(F(F(G(\frac{67}{46}))))$

It remains to deal with negative numbers and other details that I leave to the OP.

Comment: Yes, you should. My example is just to show how the algorithm works, not a proof.

Answer (score 1):

$F$, $1$ and $-\dfrac11+1=0$ allow to cover $\mathbb N$.

$G$ turns a negative fraction in a positive one.

Then for any positive irreducible fraction $\dfrac mn$, we can write

$$\frac mn=q-\frac rn=q-\frac1{\dfrac nr}$$ where $q$ is the quotient by excess, and $0<r<n$. We can iterate with $\dfrac nr$ for $\dfrac ab$, and we will reach $r=1$ after a finite number of steps.